# Tkinter progressbar and label update while loading

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a function that does some calculations and external API calls.
I want a progressBar and a Label to be updated according to the progress, but the progress bar is not moving - although the progress of the function is moving. When the function finishes only then I see the latest updated label and progress bar full.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import ttk

list = ["some","kind","of","info"]
doneCount = 0
listLen - len(list)

base = Tk()

bottomframe = Frame(base)
bottomframe.pack( side = BOTTOM )

topframe = Frame(base)
topframe.pack( side = TOP )

progressBar = ttk.Progressbar(topframe, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=250, mode='determinate')
progressBar.pack(side="bottom", expand = "true")

valueLabel = ttk.Label(topframe)
valueLabel.pack(side="bottom")


for i in list:
   try:
       #do some calculation
       doneCount +=1
       progressBar['value'] += 1 #this somewhy doesn't happen
       valueLabel['text'] = doneCount, "/", listLenght, " Done" #this not happenning
       print(doneCount, "/", listLenght, " Success")
   except:
       #catch some exceptions

       
messagebox.showinfo("After the for loop finishes - label is appearing with last value and progress bar is full")
       
mainloop()
```

When testing in Python changing the text of the label and ProgressBar value it is working - but not inside the loop - why?

Comment: What does it do instead of working? From the look of it, the whole of the loop is going to run before the window is displayed. The result is that the progress bar is immediately displayed as complete?

Comment: The Tkinter mainloop isn't running, so there's nothing to process events or handle widget updates.  `base.update_idletasks()` inside your loop might help.

Comment: @Holloway I didn't post the full code to make it easier - but you are right - the loop in my code runs inside a function that being started after clicking a button, choosing a file... so the window and all widgets are created before.

Comment: @jasonharper Ohhh.... THANKS!!!!

Comment: For something like this I would use threading to monitor your progress and pass the variable name of the tkinter widget that manages the progress bar. Then simply run an update on that progress bar within the thread. This will allow you to keep the bar updated without blocking the mainloop.

Answer (score 0):

The Tkinter mainloop isn't running, so there's nothing to process events or handle widget updates. **base.update_idletasks()** inside your loop might help. – @jasonharper

Comment: somewhere there is stuff written about how using `update` method is not the best options, however this is usable but another option would be to use `threading`